# How to type an array of anchor elements and paragraph elements in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm having this component in React TypeScript that receives `data` as a prop, which should be an array with either `a` elements or `p` elements. I'm trying to type this `data` prop but whatever I try, I can't seem to get it right.

If I try the following type:

```
interface Props {
  data: AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>[];
}
```

It will somehow accept all kinds of HTML elements, without complaining, for example:

```
// Won't complain
<Data data={[<p>hello world</p>]} />
```

Doing this type:

```
interface Props {
  data: HTMLAnchorElement[];
}
```

Will complain on the `p` tag, but will also complain on the `a` tag with this code:

```
<Data data={[<a href="/">hello world</a>]} />
```

[image]

I'm kind of in the dark now, because I'm not sure on what to do. I don't work with the HTMLElement types often, so I hope there is somebody out there that have a solution for me.

Full code to reproduce

```
import "./styles.css";
import { Data } from "./Data";

export default function App() {
  return <Data data={[<a href="/">hello world</a>]} />;
}
```

```
interface Props {
  data: HTMLAnchorElement[];
}

export const Data = ({ data }: Props) => <p>hello world</p>;
```

Answer (score 1):

Rendered JSX does not include any type information about what's inside of it.

So:

```
const foo = <a href="/">foo</a> // JSX.Element
const bar = <div>bar</div>      // JSX.Element
const baz = <p>baz</p>.         // JSX.Element
```

This means you cannot constrain the a prop that accepts JSX like this.

---

Instead, you typically want to provide the raw data needed to make the component render those for you.

For example:

```
type Props = {
  data: (
    | { type: 'link', text: string, href: string }
    | { type: 'text', text: string }
  )[]
}
```

And now you can iterate over that and render the elements you need.

```
function Data({ data }: Props) {
  return <>
    {data.map(item =>
      item.type === 'link'
        ? <a href={item.href}>{item.text}</a>
        : <p>{item.text}</p>
    )}
  </>
}
```

Which you can call like this:

```
<Data data={[
  { type: 'link', text: 'home', href: '/' },
  { type: 'text', text: 'hello' },
]} />
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCCAdmgBbQASAKgLIAy+MMUwARgK4xIDOcAvnADMoEEHADkUVBjEAoGTACeYJHAAKwsDwC8uGXDgATFDBQAuOAAo9+uAB9ccRcvNiANsEIBrMdk4APGHMuJg8Ac2wSSQEgkMJQvmt9ezwnJBd-GB9HJACY5jiE-QBKAG0AXRleOQE2YhhgCEI4ABFjFAs8IxM+c3UITSLdfUkYNigmgB4APkTcLpQAOhAUMAtgTlEtGZsbdaQQBdS4LRPxdy9ZHZ2AfjgJlDhIpAEtHD2Dp4FeKbeNw5yYLwJgB6FDbK76cwTMA-d7-AJA4Ew2ZFKr6EEzKoyCatbrzV4lawpJRpM4eby+AEuMggJBZT4uYFiPiYImOEnpAFZDLUpCuVwQZm8VllfjAqZAA)